# Photon propagator in QED in 2d space-time

Tags: quantum-field-theory, quantum-electrodynamics

Let us assume that one would like to compute perturbatively amplitudes of various processes  in QED in 2-dimensional space-time in analogy to the well known 4d case.

Is it possible? What should be the free photon propagator in that case?

Comment: Related: http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/32685/2451 and links therein.

Comment: @Qmechanic: Thank you, but apparently they do not discuss the photon propagator.

Comment: As said in the linked answer, 1D+1D doesn't work, but there are these 1.5D and 2.5D approaches releated to plasma physics which solve Maxwell like equations with 'magnetic field pointing out of dimensions' or something like that.

Comment: @MikaelKuisma: I am not sure that the 1+1 case does not work at all since there is the Schwinger model which is QED in this case. But I did not see that pertubative methods are used in its context.

Comment: @MKO The answer of Ron Maimon covers Schwinger model and other answer handles 1+1 case as well to show that only constant electric fields are allowed. But yeah, that only forbids propagation of light, but not solving the propagator, so you're right.