# Maxwell's equations in differential form in 2-space+1-time dimensions

Tags: electromagnetism, maxwell-equations, spacetime-dimensions

How does one write maxwell's equation in 2+1 dimensions? It becomes particularly interesting as the components of 2 forms and 1 form are 3. Are there any sources for this?

Comment: What do you mean by $2+1$ dimensions? $2$ space and $1$ time?

Comment: Yes. 2 space and 1 time.

Comment: [On Maxwell's electrodynamics in two spatial dimensions](https://arxiv.org/abs/1809.07368)

Comment: Another useful [link](http://dergipark.gov.tr/download/article-file/125939)

Comment: Possible duplicates: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/352632/2451 , https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/21678/2451 and links therein.

Comment: The paper by Boito (exp ikx's first link) goes through a long description of electromagnetic waves using Green's functions and Bessel functions and all kind of fancy stuff, but they never provide a straightforward description of the geometry of a plane wave, and I don't understand what they're trying to say about the Poynting vector.

Answer (score 3):

The relativistic version of Maxwell's equations,
$$ \partial_\mu \, F^{\mu\nu} = J^\nu$$
(plus the dual equation, see [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Covariant_formulation_of_classical_electromagnetism#Maxwell's_equations_in_vacuum) if that doesn't ring a bell), works fine with any number of spatial dimensions. 
Of course, $F^{\mu\nu}$ is the [field strength tensor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Covariant_formulation_of_classical_electromagnetism#Electromagnetic_tensor) and $J^\mu$ is the [relativistic current](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Covariant_formulation_of_classical_electromagnetism#Four-current).

Here's where it gets fun. In 2+1 dimensions
$$ F^{\mu\nu} = \left(
\begin{array}{ccc}
0 & -E_1 & -E_2 \\
E_1 & 0 & B \\
E_2 & -B & 0
\end{array} \right) .
$$
So the electric field is a 2d vector $\vec{E}=(E_1, E_2)$, but there's only one component of the magnetic field: $B$ is a scalar (actually a pseudoscalar)!

That's because fundamentally, $E$ is a spatial vector and $B$ is a spatial "bivector". In 3d a bivector happens to be the same as a "psuedovector", so we tend to incorrectly think of $B$ as a vector quantity. But in other numbers of dimensions that's just not the case. To get a much deeper feel for this, I'd recommend checking out the geometric algebra formulation of electrodynamics (e.g. Ch. 7 of [Doran and Lasenby](http://inspirehep.net/record/1384883)).

Answer (score 2):

The relativistic formulation of electromagnetism repackages Maxwell's equations as

$F^{a} = \int d^{3}x\,j^{b}F^{a}{}_{b}$, where $F_{ab}$ is the Maxwell Tensor given by $F_{ab} = \nabla_{[a}A_{b]}$, and $A$ is the electromagnetic potential.  In Four dimensions, it can be shown that the first equation reduces to the normal Lorentz force law, and that the Maxwell Tensor is $F_{0i} = E_{i}$ and $F_{ij} = B^{k}\epsilon_{ijk}$, where $\epsilon_{ijk}$ is the standard Levi-Civita symbol.

Then, generalizing to 2+1 dimensions is easy, because all of these equations just cross over.  All that changes is that your vector $A$ only has three components, which will mean that you have a 2-dimensional electric field, and a one-dimensional "magnetic" field.