# Can we derive the electromagnetic wave equation from $\mathcal{L}_{EM} = -\frac{1}{4} F_{\mu \nu} F^{\mu \nu} $?

Tags: electromagnetism, waves, field-theory

Where $ F_{\mu \nu}= \partial_{\mu} A_{\nu}-\partial_{\nu} A_{\mu}$, $A$ being the four-potential.

I'm interested in whether or not it's possible to show from this:  $$ \frac{1}{\epsilon_0 \mu_0} E_{xx} = E_{tt}$$

Lower index meaning partial derivative. Sticking to (1+1) dimensions for simplicity.

Comment: What have you tried?

Comment: You get equations of motion from varying Lagrangians, so yes, give it a try.

Comment: Possible duplicate: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/32685/2451 and links therein.

Answer (score 0):

This really does need all three space dimensions. I'll set $\mu_0=\epsilon_0=1$ to tidy up; feel free to restore them. Since $\partial_\mu F^{\mu\nu}=0$, $\nabla\cdot E=0$ and $\nabla\times B=\dot{E}$. Since $\partial_\mu\tilde{F}^{\mu\nu}=0$, $\nabla\cdot B=0$ and $\nabla\times E=-\dot{B}$. So$$\ddot{E}=\nabla\times\dot{B}=-\nabla\times\nabla\times E=\Delta E.$$