# Tensor notation of Maxwell's equations

Tags: electromagnetism, special-relativity, maxwell-equations, tensor-calculus

Tensor notation of Maxwell's equation read

$$\partial_\mu F^{\mu\nu} = j^\nu.$$

So when we explicitly try to find the Maxwell's equation from the above tensor equation we only get gauss law and curl of B. The div.B=0 and curl of E are not present. What is happening here??
I have obtained the above tensor equation from the four maxwell equation but when i try explicitly write the equation component wise some how two of those equations dont appear? 
I know it has something to do with two of those equations not being equations of motion, but i m still very unclear about this.

Comment: Hello. As written in the answer of Mr Logan below, to derive Maxwell' s equations from the Faraday tensor you need both the relationships, the one you mention and the other in the answer, since in general $F_{ab} = 2u_{[a} E_{b]} + ε_{abc} B^c $. and  $E_a= F_{ab} u^b $ $ B_a=ε_{abc} F^{bc} /2$.

Comment: The equation you wrote show that there exist a fluid that produces the field, and the Bianchi shows the existence of a potential.

Comment: Related Lagrangian question: http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/71611/2451 and links therein.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[As is written here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Electromagnetic_tensor#Significance)  the two remaining equations follow from the Bianchi identity which says that the anti-symmetrized derivative is zero, ie.
$$
\partial_{[a} F_{bc]} =  \partial_{a} F_{bc}+\partial_{b} F_{ca}+\partial_{c} F_{ab} = 0
$$
(remember the $F_{\mu\nu}$ is antisymmetric itself!)

Comment: Still very unclear.. Can u show some detailed math?

Comment: @SiddharthaDam Alternatively consider that if $A_\mu$ is the vector potential, then $F_{\mu\nu}=\partial_\mu A_\nu-\partial_\nu A_\mu$. The Bianchi identity follows trivially if you expand this. Or, in differential forms notation $F=\mathrm{d}A$, and it is a well known and easily derivable identity that $\mathrm{d}^2=0$, and the Bianchi identity essentially states that $\mathrm{d}^2F=0$.