# Does Gauss-Faraday law play any role in the quantization of the electromagnetic field?

Tags: electromagnetism, quantum-field-theory, quantum-electrodynamics, field-theory

The Gauss-Faraday law, in the covariant form, reads

$
\epsilon^{\alpha\beta\gamma\delta} F_{\gamma\delta,\alpha} = 0,
$

while the vacuum field equation is

$
\partial_\mu F^{\mu\nu} = 0.
$

When it comes to quantize the electromagnetic field $A^\mu$, only the field equation is considered (as far as I know). So my question is: does the Gauss-Faraday law play any role in QFT?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The Gauss-Faraday law can be viewed as the integrability condition for the existence of the electro-magnetic $4$-potential $A_{\mu}$ via [Poincare Lemma](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Closed_and_exact_differential_forms).

Or conversely, assuming a globally defined electro-magnetic $4$-potential $A_{\mu}$, the Gauss-Faraday law is trivially satisfied. See also [this](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/71611/2451) related Phys.SE post.

So yes, Gauss-Faraday law plays a role already before quantization.

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong, but mathematically this law is just $$\partial_\mu \star F^{\mu\nu} = 0$$ isn't it? Where $\star F^{\mu\nu}$ is the Hodge dual. Here's an [explicit proof](http://farside.ph.utexas.edu/teaching/em/lectures/node122.html) that this condition is always satisfied when the EM tensor exists, in case it helps the OP.

Comment: $\uparrow$ You are right.

Answer (score 0):

The Gauss-Faraday law in the QFT plays essential role, as well as $\partial_{\mu}F^{\mu\nu} = 0$. In fact, this is related to the fact that in the QFT quantum fields represent irreducible representations of the Poincare group, i.e., the particles. The photon is massless particle with helicities 1, -1, therefore it has only two degrees of freedom, and it can be shown that the corresponding field is $F_{\mu\nu}$ satisfyng above two equations.