# Deriving the field-equation for the electromagnetic field in modified theory

Tags: electromagnetism, lagrangian-formalism, field-theory

Given the lagrangian density written in the following form
$$
\mathcal{L} \propto \frac{\mathcal{L}_{(EM)}^2}{R}
$$
where $R$ stands for the Ricci tensor and $\mathcal{L}_{(EM)}$ stands for the usual electromagnetic matter lagrangian defined as
$$
\mathcal{L}_{(EM)} = -\frac{F^2}{2}.
$$

The field equation for $A_{\mu}$, using the Euler-Lagrange equation follows:
$$
\frac{1}{4}\partial_{\lambda}\frac{\partial \mathcal{L}_{(EM)}^2}{\partial(\partial_{\lambda}A_{\rho})} = \frac{1}{4} \partial_{\lambda} \frac{\partial}{\partial(\partial_{\lambda}A_{\rho})} (F^{\mu \nu}F_{\mu \nu} F^{\alpha \beta}F_{\alpha \beta}) = \frac{1}{4} \partial_{\lambda} \left( \frac{\partial(F^{\mu \nu}F_{\mu \nu}) F^{\alpha \beta}F_{\alpha \beta}}{\partial(\partial_{\lambda}A_{\rho})} + F^{\mu \nu}F_{\mu \nu} \frac{\partial(F^{\alpha \beta}F_{\alpha \beta}) }{\partial(\partial_{\lambda}A_{\rho})} \right)
$$
from the standard derivation of Maxwell's equation:
$$
 = \frac{1}{4} \partial_{\lambda} ( 4 F^{\lambda \rho} F^2 + 4 F^2 F^{\lambda \rho}) = 4 \partial_{\lambda} (F^{\lambda \rho} F^2)
$$
therefore, the field equation is
$$
\nabla_{\lambda} (F^{\lambda \rho} F^2) = 0.
$$
(Where, clearly, the other term depending on $A_{\mu}$ in the Euler-Lagrange equation vanishes)

Is this procedure correct? What about the other Maxwell equation (that usually reads $\nabla_{[\alpha}F_{\beta \gamma]} = 0$)?

Comment: The other equation follows from $F_{\beta\gamma}=\nabla_\beta A_\gamma-\nabla_\gamma A_\beta$.

Comment: So this equation is valid for any non-standard electromagnetic theory?

Comment: Only the first equation changes if we add e.g. an $A\cdot j$ term to induce source dependence. We therefore call it the sourced equation; it's the equivalent of Newton's second law for the $A$-field. But the second equation can generalize too, if you introduce magnetic charges.

Comment: (See in particular [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magnetic_monopole#Tensor_formulation).)

Comment: Hi Edison Santos. The Bianchi identities $\nabla_{[\alpha}F_{\beta \gamma]} = 0$ hold off-shell even before varying the action, cf. e.g. https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/71611/2451

Comment: Now I am almost 100% sure that my calculation is correct. Should I close delete this question?