Why the tensor form of the Maxwell equation without any sources only contain two equations?
This is the Maxwell equation written in the book in vacuum, but when I plug the strong tensor Fσρ into formula to calculate, found that it seems to be missing two equations (the divergence of the magnetic field and the curl of the electric field), this is why?


Essentially a duplicate of https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/71611/2451 and links therein.

Can you write the "strong tensor $F^{\sigma\rho}$" you were using? And how you only have 2 equations with a single free index (which ought to suggest 4 equations)

Two of the four equations are in fact identities, so no need to write them.
