# Why does Maxwell's equations $\partial_{\mu} F^{\mu \nu} = 0$ have 3 independent components (DOF) in $D = 4$?

Tags: electromagnetism, gauge-theory, maxwell-equations, gauge-invariance, degrees-of-freedom

And how can we generalize this to the statement that it has $D-1$ independent components in dimension $D$?

I know that $F_{\mu \nu}$ has six independent components (because of antisymmetry), how do I go from there?

Comment: Related: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/20071/2451 , https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/457269/2451 and links therein.

Answer (score 4):

First, I'll address a language issue: "independent components" can mean two different things:

- The statement that $F_{\mu\nu}$ has six independent components is a statement about the number of parameters required to specify an antisymmetric matrix.
- The statement that $\partial^\mu F_{\mu\nu}=0$ has three independent components is a statement about the number of *functions* required to specify a solution of this differential equation.

The question about the number of independent functions required to specify a solution is answered in https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/20072/206691, so this could potentially be marked as a duplicate question. That other answer uses a different notation, though, so I'll offer a version that uses the current OP's notation.

I'll write $j,k$ for spatial indices and $0$ for the time index. 
Suppose that we have some solution $F_{\mu\nu}$ to 
$$
\partial^\mu F_{\mu k}=0
\tag{1}
$$
 but that we have not made any attempt yet to enforce 
$$
\partial^\mu F_{\mu 0}=0.
\tag{2}
$$
Equation (2) is equivalent to
$$
\partial^k F_{0k}=0.
\tag{3}
$$
Equation (3) is a **constraint**: it is a condition that the initial data must satisfy, rather than a condition on how that data evolves in time. 
Applying $\partial^k$ to equation (1) gives
$$
\partial^\mu \partial^k F_{\mu k}=0.
\tag{4}
$$
In equation (4), the terms with $\mu\neq 0$ are *identically* zero because $F$ is antisymmetric, so equation (4) is equivalent to
$$
\partial^0 \partial^k F_{0 k}=0.
\tag{5}
$$
In words, this says that if the functions $F_{\mu\nu}$ that we chose to satisfy equations (1) for all times are also chosen to satisfy the constraint (2) at some *initial* time, then they *automatically* satisfy the constraint (2) for *all* times.  In this sense, a solution to $\partial^\mu F_{\mu\nu}=0$ in $D$-dimensional spacetime has only $D-1$ independent components.

Summary: Equation (1), which involves time-derivatives, has $D-1$ components (the number of values of the spatial index $k$). Equation (3) does not involve time-derivatives; it imposes a constraint on the initial data rather than an additional condition on how that data evolves in time.

Answer (score 0):

There are 3 dofs for the three spatial directions. Then there are two directions - time reversal symmetry. Taking polarisation into account one has 12 independent solutions, per frequency. That is a lot of dofs.