# Counting degrees of freedom in theories with two-forms

Tags: field-theory, gauge-theory, constrained-dynamics, degrees-of-freedom, gauge

I am reading [Counting the number of propagating degrees of freedom in Lorenz Gauge Electrodynamics](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/119756/). I am thinking that I can apply the same arguments to the case of a two form, whose components are denoted as $B_{\mu\nu}$.

Can I still claim, if the two-form field $B_{\mu\nu}$ in 4D is massless, that I can remove one degree of freedom from the equation $k^2=0$, and another just by choosing to work in Lorenz gauge? If this is true, then I will be left with 6-1-1=4 free components of the antisymmetric gauge field.

Is the above argument true? If so, can I impose other restrictions regarding the gauge, that can remove some other number of degrees of freedom from my problem?

Comment: Possible duplicate: [How many degrees of freedom in a massless 2
-form field?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/457269/2451)