# Is this a holographic principle?

Tags: holographic-principle, analyticity

The idea of the holographic principle is that all the data about what's inside a volume can be discribed by fields on it's boundary.

But... isn't this just obvious calculus?

e.g. take a field in polar coordinates $\phi(r,\theta,\rho)$ with $r<1$.

The boundary of this volume is at $r=1$. We can define an infinite set of fields:

$$\Phi_n(\theta,\rho) = \frac{\partial^n}{\partial r^n}\phi(r,\theta,\rho)|_{r=1}.$$

These fields live on the boundary. The field inside the boundary can be reconstructed by a simple Taylor series:

$$\phi(r,\theta,\rho) \equiv \sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{1}{n!}(r-1)^n \Phi_n(\theta,\rho).$$

So it's easy to create a set of fields on the boundary that are equivalent to fields on the interior. Assuming the fields are analytic. So what's so special about the holographic principle?

Comment: One would think that to know the state of a system one would have to acquire all the information in the volume instead of the surface alone.

Comment: You answered your own question when you wrote "Assuming the fields are analytic." Analytic fields satisfy Laplace's equation, but other fields could satisfy Poisson's equation, or more general ones.

Comment: @Halsey, So it seems to me like the holographic principle is saying the fields have a special property akin to being analytic which allows them to be written as fields on a boundary. Still this doesn't seem as mindblowing as first thought.

Answer (score 2):

In the [holographic principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Holographic_principle) for [quantum gravity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quantum_gravity) the [DOF](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Degrees_of_freedom_(physics_and_chemistry))s are encoded on a spacetime codimension-2 [Cauchy surface](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy_surface). A conventional [hyperbolic system](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hyperbolic_partial_differential_equation) has a spacetime codimension-1 Cauchy surface. A Taylor series $f(x)=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{f^{(n)}(0)}{n!}x^n$ is typically not viewed as an example of holography. For starters because we usually don't require [analyticity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Analytic_function) of physical fields. In fact, typically only a finite number of derivatives are important in physical theories, cf. e.g. [this](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/4102/2451) & [this](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/18588/2451) Phys.SE posts. See also [this](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/483179/2451) related Phys.SE post.

Comment: True, but the solutions to the wave equation are usually analytic functions. Except at poles. So classical fields are usually discribed by analytic functions.