# A strange formulation of the Maxwell's equations

Tags: electromagnetism, differential-geometry, maxwell-equations

I am working on a project that involves Maxwell's equations, and the research paper that I am working on has formulated the equations in a strange and unfamiliar way. Here are the four equations (1)-(4):

$\oint_{\partial A} \mathbf{E} \cdot \mathrm{d}\boldsymbol{s} =  -\iint_{A} \frac{\partial \mathbf{B}}{\partial t} \cdot \mathrm{d}\mathbf{A}$

$\oint_{\partial A} \mathbf{H} \cdot \mathrm{d}\boldsymbol{s} = \iint_{A} \left(\frac{\partial \mathbf{D}}{\partial t} + \mathbf{J}\right) \cdot \mathrm{d}\mathbf{A}$

$\iint_{\partial \mathbf{V}} \mathbf{B} \cdot \mathrm{d}\mathbf{A} = 0$

$\iint_{\partial \mathbf{V}} \left(\frac{\partial \mathbf{D}}{\partial t} + \mathbf{J}\right) \cdot \mathrm{d}\mathbf{A} = 0$

With the following relation equations (5)-(7):

$D=\epsilon E$, $B=\mu H$, and $J=\kappa E + \rho v$

I got the first 3 equation, which are respectively Maxwell-Faraday, Maxwell Ampere and Guass's law for magnetism. What I do not get is the supposed Gauss's law (4th equation), which does not look like a Gauss'S law to me as well as the last relation equation relating the current density with the E field and the movement of the particles inside the medium.
Mind someone shedding some light over the two?
I would be extremely thankful since I have been pulling my hair to understand them since two weeks.

The paper mentioning the formulation can be found here:
https://doi.org/10.1016/0010-4655(92)90026-U

Answer (score 2):

This is a strange notation. You have for any $\mathbf F$ vector field   $\int_{\mathcal V}  dV \text{div} \mathbf F  = \oint_{\partial \mathcal V} \mathbf F  \cdot d\mathbf A$ , where $\oint$ is a surface integral and ${\partial \mathcal V}$ is the *closed* boundary surface of the volume ${\mathcal V}$.

Apply this to $\mathbf {curl H}=\mathbf {J + \dot D}$ and note that $\text{div}\mathbf {curl}=0$, you get $$\oint_{\partial \mathcal V} (\mathbf {J + \dot D})  \cdot d\mathbf A=0$$

The same argument holds for Eq.3 where $\text{div}\mathbf B = 0$, thus
$$\oint_{\partial \mathcal V} \mathbf {B}  \cdot d\mathbf A=0$$

Answer (score 2):

The usual $\mathrm{div}~{\bf B}=0$ and $\mathrm{div}~{\bf D}=\rho$ equations are not dynamical equations (they do not contain time derivatives, see for example, [this question](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/20071/do-maxwells-equations-overdetermine-the-electric-and-magnetic-fields?noredirect=1&lq=1)). Thus, they can be considered as a constraint on the initial condition, provided their time derivative is zero. Indeed, the vanishing of the time derivatives is ensured by the validity of the *curl* equations and the continuity equation for the current. In an integral formulation, such a condition must be explicitly present.

The last equation is nothing but the condition that
$$
\frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}t} \int_{V} \left(\mathrm{div}~\mathbf{D} - \rho\right) \cdot \mathrm{d}V =0
$$