# How many independent equations do Maxwell's equations represent in arbitrary dimensions?

Tags: electromagnetism, maxwell-equations, spacetime-dimensions, degrees-of-freedom

In an arbitrary number of spacetime dimensions $D$, Maxwell's equations are
\begin{align*}
\mathrm{d}F &= 0, \\
\mathrm{d}(\star F) &= -J.
\end{align*}

How many independent equations does this represent for arbitary $D$?

Comment: This is explained in my Phys.SE answer [here](https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/20578/2451).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think the second equation is missing a $*$. The first one has n(n-1)(n-2)/6 independent equations (it's setting a 3 form equal to 0 and there's one equation for $dx_idx_jdx_k$ for each $i, j,k$ distinct and order doesn't matter). The second equation is one of 1 forms so it has $n$ independent equations. This yields a total of $(n^3-3n^2+8n)/6$ independent equations. For $n=4$, this yields 8 as expected.

Comment: *I think the second equation is missing a ∗.* [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maxwell%27s_equations#Relativistic_formulations) leaves out the second Hodge star on the inhomogeneous equation and considers the current density to be a 3-form. So how does that approach — with two 3-form equations — give the same counting for arbitrary dimension as one 3-form and one 1-form?

Comment: it's not a 3 form - the dual of a 2 form is an n-2 form, d of this is an n-1 form ("pseudo vector"), the dimension of this space is also n. Under this convention, j is generally a pseudovector, not a 3 form.

Comment: The second bullet point explicitly says “$J$ … is the current 3-form”.

Comment: Yes, it is a 3 form in 4 dimensions, but looking at the definition of J_a *dx_a (which generalizes), it's an n-1 form generally

Comment: OK, I understand now. I upvoted.